# Checking dimensions of View in MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I want to get dimensions of View defined in activity_main.xml to create a `Bitmap` based on height and width. Writing them in `textView` shows 0 or stops app. I checked if this view is `null`, but it's not. Can I get dimensions of view this way?

Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.view);
    int x = view.getMeasuredWidth();
    int y = view.getHeight();
    int radius = 10;

    textView.setText(view.getHeight());

// if (view == null) textView.setText("View is null");
// else textView.setText("View is not null");

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Here is actvity_main.xml:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
    android:background="@color/green"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="209dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Check `textView.setText(String.valueOf(y));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are trying to set integer value in `TextView` in this line `textView.setText(view.getHeight());` Try Convert it in String an then set as follows.

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(view.getHeight()));
```

for getting view either use above line in `onResume` or use as follows

```
textView.post(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(view.getHeight()));
        }
    });
```

I hope it's work for you
Thank You

Comment: And it displays 0. I don't know why.
I expect it will display 400.

Comment: use same line in onResume  because in onCreate view just created

Answer (score 1):

getWidth and height will return 0 as long as the view has not been layedout.

in order to get the dimensions at the right moment you have 2 options:

1. add a `ViewTreeObserver` in onCreate and remove it when it gets called.

2.(i think is easier) add a runnable to the view as i have showed at the bottom:

```
    view.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int x = view.getMeasuredWidth();
                int y = view.getHeight();
            }
        })
```

the `post()` method callback gets called only after the view inflating is done.

happy coding

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this solution

```
int height;
int width;
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = view.getViewTreeObserver(); 
viewTreeObserver .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override public void onGlobalLayout () {
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        height = view.getLayoutParams().height;
        width = view.getLayoutParams().width;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code :)

```
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

Now you can use `height` and `width` variable in your project